# Strange issue comparing numbers inside switch

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to generate the css class name from the category id using `switch case` like this.

I have mutiple conditions in switch case, but we will look only this one as its creating strange output.

Sample code:

```
<?php
$value = '907';//base value

$value_array =  str_split($value);//create array of string, if its int.

var_dump($value_array);//debug whats in array

switch($value_array[0]){

case 9:

$final = 'i came inside 9';

if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] == 07){
//check whther last 2 digits are 07
    $final = 'i came inside 907';
}else if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] == 09){
//chcek whether last 2 digits are 09
    $final = 'i came inside 909';
}
break;
}

echo $final;
```

The above code gives output as `[$value is 907]`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
i came inside 907
```

Which is the correct behavior. But if I change the base value from 907 to 909, then output comes as `[$value is 909]`.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
i came inside 9
```

The output should be `i came inside 909`.

- Why is that?
- Why did it work for `907` and not for `909`, even though both have the same data type?
- I know they are strings and I should compare string with string, but why is it working with one example and not with another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`07` and `09` are [octal numbers](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php), where `09` is an invalid octal number, so it will end up as 0. That's why your code doesn't work as you want it to.

To solve it just put it in quotes, e.g.

```
if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] === "07"){
//check whther last 2 digits are 07
    $final = 'i came inside 907';
}else if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] === "09"){
//chcek whether last 2 digits are 09
    $final = 'i came inside 909';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the array value with an integer formatted as octal number (see http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php).

`07` is a valid octal number an represents the value `7` and your comparison works.

`09` on the other hand is an invalid octal number. Therefore the comparison doesn't work.

In order to fix your issue you need to put ' around the values so they're interpreted as strings.

```
if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] == '07'){
//check whther last 2 digits are 07
    $final = 'i came inside 907';
}else if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] == '09'){
//chcek whether last 2 digits are 09
    $final = 'i came inside 909';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `07`, PHP [interprets it as an octal number](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). It knows that `09` is not octal, because `9` is not valid in the Octal system.

Try `7` and `9`, or `'07'` and `'09'`.

```
<?php
$value = '907'; //base value

$value_array =  str_split($value); //create array of string, if its int.

var_dump($value_array); //debug whats in array

switch ($value_array[0])
{
    case 9:
        $final = 'i came inside 9';

        if ($value_array[1].$value_array[2] == '07')
        {
            //check whther last 2 digits are 07
            $final = 'i came inside 907';
        }
        elseif($value_array[1].$value_array[2] == '09')
        {
            //chcek whether last 2 digits are 09
            $final = 'i came inside 909';
        }

        break;
}

echo $final;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in php `09` will consider it as octal number and convert it into `0` where as for `07` its always `07`

When you try to `echo 09` it'll output you `0` and for `07` its `07`

So instead of comparing it loosely `==` you need to use strict comparison `===` i.e

```
if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] === "07"){
//check whther last 2 digits are 07
    $final = 'i came inside 907';
}else if($value_array[1].$value_array[2] === "09"){
//chcek whether last 2 digits are 09
    $final = 'i came inside 909';
}
```